# Pokemon tcg knock out attacks versus effects

Tags: pokemon

Is the Amazing Destruction (Yveltal) knock out an effect or part of the attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shining Fates Amazing Rare Yveltal](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/ss-series/swsh45/46/) has the following attack text:

> Amazing Destruction
>
> > Your opponent’s Active Pokémon is Knocked Out.

That is an attack, and the effect of that attack is that the opponent’s Pokémon is knocked out. A Pokémon that was protected from the effects of attacks would be protected from that; it is not dealing damage.

Comment: So a card like Big Parasol would block it I assume?

Comment: Correct. Big Parasol would block it from doing anything if it were on the active Pokémon.

Comment: I wonder if Hero's medal applies here. The card mentions "damage from an attack", but this move doesn't inflict dmg.

Comment: same thing for experience share, cursed shovel, rocky helmet, etc...

Comment: Right - [Experience share says](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/sm-series/sm1/118/) "damage from an attack", so it would not proc here, nor would any other card that says "damage from an attack".

Comment: Note that damage *counters* are also *not* damage from an attack, so attacks that place damage counters (Bench Barrier Mew's attack, for example) would not proc these things either.